# MYSQL - search field for unordered text

Tags: mysql

I'm having problems trying to query the following data:

```
id. | name | type

 1.    bob | a 
 2.    sam | ab
 3.    jim | abc
 4.  sarah | ad
 5.   john | a
 6.    eve | bca
 7.  nikki | ca
```

I'm trying to write a MySQL query based on the following input:

```
a,
ac,
b*,
ac*
```

which I want to return the following names:

```
bob
john
sam
jim
eve
nikki
```

**Breakdown:**

```
a  = bob, john
ac = nikki  
b* = sam, jim, eve
ac*= jim, eve, nikki
```

**Explained:**

```
a  = find results that are JUST a
ac = find results that contain ONLY an a AND c
b* = find results which contains a b
ac*  find results that contain at least an a and a c
```

As can be seen the type column can contain type info in different orders (not always increasing).

I'm sure this could be done by splitting the type column into `type_a`, `type_b` etc etc and then just have a `bool` in each one. But this could go up to `z` and I don't want 26 extra cols on my table!

is this possible to do in a single query, if so any help would be appreciated!

Sorry about the title I had no idea what to call it

Comment: Why `ac` and `ac*` return `nikki`?

Comment: as nikki contains an ac. So she gets picked up in the just ac part and also in the ac* (to clarify ac* mean anything with a or c and/or any other letters

Comment: `nikki` does not contain an `ac`, just a `c`. Should `ac*` match `a AND с (and possibly others)` or `a OR c (and possibly others)`?

Comment: my apologies I had missed off the c for nikki. She should be "ca"

ca* should be a AND c AND others

Comment: I suspect your database structure (and therefore this query) could be simplified through [normalisation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization): perhaps the `type` column should be replaced with a `Types` table consisting of `(user_id,type)` pairs?

Comment: @eggyal . I would have liked to have done this but the information is added via a manual csv upload into phpmyadmin.. The person who would be doing this upload struggles enough uploading one let alone two sheets! haha.. But you're correct this would have been easier!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [regular expressions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html):

```
SELECT name FROM your_table WHERE
     type RLIKE '^a+$'                            -- only 'a'
  OR type RLIKE '^((a[ac]*c)|(c[ac]*a))[ac]*$'    -- only & both 'a' AND 'c'
  OR type RLIKE 'b'                               -- at least one 'b'
  OR type RLIKE '(a.*c)|(c.*a)'                   -- at least 'a' and 'c'
;
```

Comment: what is the second predicate intended to match?

Comment: the second predicate will match `a` only, `c` only or an empty string.

Comment: @Quassnoi: The character class `[ac]` is repeated (it previously was using `*`, now with `+`).  Granted that I hadn't considered empty strings though - now corrected.  Thanks.

Comment: what I wanted to say is that @op's intention was not to match a string of, say, `'c'` only. Your query, as it is now, will match it.

Comment: Just came back as i had the same problem to see a solution; Excellent work! Though quick question... What about if I wanted to do cba* or cba?

Comment: @james: You should probably read up on regular expressions (although I grant you that they're not the easiest thing to understand when one first sees them!) - I'm sure Google can guide you towards some beginners' tutorials.  Sadly MySQL doesn't support an advanced feature of regular expressions called "back-references", which would make queries for cba* and cba a lot shorter; alternatively, if you know for certain that a character can only appear at most once, one can also make some simplifications; otherwise for cba*: `(a.*b.*c)|(a.*c.*b)|(b.*a.*c)|(b.*c.*a)|(c.*a.*b)|(c.*b.*a)`

Comment: ...and for cba:  `^((a[abc]*b[abc]*c)|(a[abc]*c[abc]*b)|(b[abc]*a[abc]*c)|(b[abc]*c[abc]*a)|(c[abc]*a[abc]*b)|(c[abc]*b[abc]*a))[abc]*$`  (it's horrible, isn't it?)

Comment: i'm starting to think maybe it will just be too complex to do it this way. Which is a shame, but would you suggest my best option would be to create extra fields type_a, type_b, type_c etc etc... and then just have a bool in each one and then just do a query like (for 'ac*') where (type_a = true AND type_b = true) or for 'ac' where (type_a = true AND type_c = true AND type_b = false AND type_D = false ... etc etc

Comment: @james:  If the number of possible types is fixed (i.e. new ones aren't likely to pop up with new data), then that's definitely a better solution than what you have currently (strings really aren't intended to represent a set of data like this).  Otherwise, as mentioned above, I'd consider having a `UserTypes` table that contains an entry for every `(user_id, type)` pair.

Answer (score 1):

```
-- ac*, ac, a, b*

SELECT  *
FROM    mytable
WHERE   (
        type RLIKE 'a'
        AND type RLIKE 'c'
        )
        OR
        (
        type RLIKE 'a'
        AND type RLIKE 'c'
        AND NOT type RLIKE '[^ac]'
        )
        OR
        (
        type RLIKE 'a'
        AND NOT type RLIKE '[^a]'
        )
        OR
        (
        type RLIKE 'b'
        );
```

This won't use any indexes though.

If your table is `MyISAM`, you can store types like this:

```
id   name     type
7    nikki    a c
```

(note the spaces) and use `FULLTEXT` functionality:

```
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX fx_mytable_type ON mytable (type);

-- ac*
SELECT  *
FROM    mytable
WHERE   MATCH(type) AGAINST '+"a" + "c"' IN BOOLEAN MODE);


-- ac
SELECT  *
FROM    mytable
WHERE   MATCH(type) AGAINST '+"a" + "c"' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
        AND NOT TYPE RLIKE '[^ ac]' -- note the space
```

Set `@@ft_min_word_len = 1` for this to work.

Comment: thank very much will try this out. though is this possible to do multiple queries in a single call? or would i be better doing each one as its own query and then just removing the duplicates from the results?

Comment: @james: which duplicates? Each search string translates into one query.

Comment: If i run 3 queries I would get 3 sets of results which may contain duplicate results (as some names will match more than one query)

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to be building the queries programmatically (basically just passing an array("ab","ac","b","ab*") to generate the query. So i'm going to try both yours and @eggyal ways to see which is easier to generate

Comment: @james: a string like `'abcdef'` will require you to generate a regexp with `720` (seven hundred twenty) permutations.

Comment: ahh, good point.. would this also be the case with your first example (the indexless one)?

Comment: @james: no, and neither with my second example. For the second example, just `OR` the predicates in the same way.